$wpdb->get_results() query empty, but same query in phpmyadmin has results
I'm running the following query to get attachment data for a long list of post ids:
SELECT post_id, post_title, meta_key, meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
WHERE post_id IN ('list', 'of', 'around', '2500', 'post', 'ids', ...)
AND meta_key IN ('_wp_attachment_metadata', '_wp_attachment_image_alt', '_wp_attached_file')

Making this query with $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A) returns an empty array.  But when I run the exact same query in phpmyadmin, I get results.
Wordpress docs say that an empty array is returned when there are no results, or when there is a mysql error, but $wpdb->last_error is empty.  Is there is a limitation in $wpdb regarding query length (I'm not seeing anything in the docs)?  Any ideas?

I would not always trust that there are no DB errors if $wpdb->last_error empty. Might check  $wpdb->last_query. Also start with a simple  query and build up. Wonder if you can use taxonomy instead, multiple queries or something else than huge list of post ids.

When you use $wpdb->get_results() are you passing the same exact string, or are you using variables or query preparation? If you're not just using the exact same string then the issue is likely something to do with how you've created the query string.

@JacobPeattie I'm copying the $query string in my example above, which has already been passed through $wpdb->prepare(), so it's the exact same string.

@birgire If I limit the "IN" clause to a list of 2000 ids the query works, so it's something to do with the size of the query I guess.  $wpdb->last_query returns a strange error-like message when it fails: " /* From [{redacted}.com/wp-json/prophoto/visual-builder?design_id=c250fc27-609a-4dd2-8d33-86e360aee194&p7_tech_debug=1] in [/nas/content/live/{redacted}/wp-content/themes/prophoto8/src/php/core/Data/Queries/Embedded/QueriesAttachments.php:34] */" (redacted some bits for privacy).
